# Extract link from iframe

Tags: r, iframe, web-scraping, rvest

Hi From the following link i am trying to extract the link to the document of the summary prospectus

http://quicktake.morningstar.com/EtfNet/SecFiling.aspx?Symbol=MTUM

I do not understand what i am doing wrong. At the moment output is just NA

```
library(rvest)

read_html("http://quicktake.morningstar.com/EtfNet/SecFiling.aspx?Symbol=MTUM") %>% 
  html_node("iframe") %>% 
  html_attr("src") %>% 
  read_html() -> pg

input <- html_node(pg, xpath=".//div[contains(.,'/Summary-Prospectus/')][1]") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: Please do not include `rm(list=ls())` (or anything else with significant side effects) as actual code: though unlikely, it is feasible somebody would copy your code and run in their current namespace, potentially wiping out "good things". (I tend to use a fresh R instance with SO questions, but mistakes still happen.)

Comment: Thanks, will avoid